# Generic field causes StackOverflowError by initialization

Tags: generics, kotlin, spring-data-mongodb

I extended my model class with the following field:

`val errors: List<ValidationError<out Any>> = emptyList()`

and since then my application context cannot be built. Something is being called recursively by initialising the `mongoMappingContext`.

Do you know how can I handle this?

Some code for `ValidationError` class:

```
data class ValidationError<T : Any>(
    val objectType: KClass<T>,
    //other fields
)
```

My stack trace:

```
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'reactiveMongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoReactiveDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'reactiveMongoTemplate' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingMongoConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDbFactoryDependentConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mappingMongoConverter' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoMappingContext' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDataConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:787)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:226)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
```

Comment: Is this question related to `spring-data-mongodb` really?

Comment: I think yes, why not. The reactive repository implementation has difficulties with generic.
MongoDB itself does not have.